# Make a dictionary from csv columns in pandas in python

Tags: pandas

I have 3 column csv file, with column headings {id, ingredients, recipe}

Now, I want to create a dictionary in a way, `id` is the `key` and `ingredients and recipe` is the `value`.

When combining `ingredients` and `recipe`, I need to insert `a fullstop and a whitespace` as well.
e.g., `<ingredient>. <recipe>`

My current code is as follows.

```
input_data = pd.read_csv( input_file, header=0, delimiter="\t", quoting=3 )
L= input_data["ingredient"] + '. ' + input_data["recipe"]
my_d = input_data.set_index('id')[L].to_dict()
```

Please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip` with `dict`:

```
my_d = dict(zip(input_data['id'], input_data["ingredient"] + '. ' + input_data["recipe"]))
```

Sample:

```
input_data = pd.DataFrame({'ingredient':list('abg'),
                           'id':[1,2,4],
                           'recipe':list('rth')})

print (input_data)
   id ingredient recipe
0   1          a      r
1   2          b      t
2   4          g      h

my_d = dict(zip(input_data['id'], input_data["ingredient"] + '. ' + input_data["recipe"]))
print (my_d)
{1: 'a. r', 2: 'b. t', 4: 'g. h'}
```